# UITableViewCell separator not showing up

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, separator

I made a custom UITableViewCell in IB, but for some reason, despite the single line option for separator being selected, there are no separator lines on my table.

Has this happened to any of you before?  What gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Is the UITableViewCell in IB associated with a UITableViewCell subclass that overrides `drawRect:`?  If so, make sure you are calling the super implementation, as that's what draws the line at the bottom.  If you are overriding `layoutSubviews` make sure no views are obscuring the bottom of the cell.

Comment: Also, if you're overriding layoutSubviews, make sure you call [super layoutSubviews]; first

Answer (score 53):

Just a heads up even though this is an old post:

If you are using the simulator and the UITableView separator is not showing up between cells it may be due to the fact that your window scale is too small.

Change this by going to Window->Scale->100%

Comment: That was the reason in my case. Took me hours to figure.

Comment: God! I've been struggling with this for hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

In my case, i forgot to call [super layoutSubviews] after overriding the layoutSubviews method. Took me two hours to find the problem.

Comment: yeah ... i also had the same issue

Comment: This is definitely "a thing", just ran into it, so thx. Does anyone know WHY this is the case though?

Comment: I just did this too.

Comment: This was my issue.

Answer (score 4):

in my case I have to set the separatorStyle property of the tableView

`tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;`

Answer (score 1):

I found `separatorStyle` in [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/separatorStyle).
It says it will add separatorStyle to the cell returned by the delegate method, [tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

So, I think you should modify the style property on the UITableView instance.

Comment: You can't assign separator style in this method.

Comment: @Shmidt, I read the apple document again, http://goo.gl/FgTirp.  **UITableView uses this property to set the separator style on the cell returned from the delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.**

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this: My issue was that I had multiple sections, and the first cell in each section didn't have a separator. In my table view, I had overwritten the heightForHeader function (returning 0). Deleting this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an unlikely case, but there's another possible cause.

I have a custom `UITableView` called AddressBookTableView and it is included in a .XIB for one of my view controllers. The thing I noticed was that it had been added as a `UIView` element with custom class specified to be AddressBookTableView. I deleted this element and added a `UITableView` element instead whose class I again specified to be AddressBookTableView and the separators magically reappeared!

Took me a super long time to find this...

**Make sure your custom `UITableView` .XIB elements are indeed custom `UITableView` elements NOT renamed `UIView` elements.**

To be honest I'm surprised that the only noticeable artifact of this mistake was that the separators were missing. Other than that the UITableView still functioned normally?

Answer (score 0):

If you programmatically add subviews to your cell, make sure you add the subviews

to **cell.contentView** and NOT to *cell*

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:subview];
```