# UITableView some separator line missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using code to build a uitableview like this:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 290, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 290)]; 
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"settingtabcell"];
```

And the dataresource and viewdelegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"settingtabcell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }else{
        for(UIView *subview in cell.subviews){
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20, 90)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 32, 32)];
    
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            label.text = @"Copyright information";
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"copyright.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
            label.text = @"Clear cache";
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clearcache.png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            label.text = @"Feedback";
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"feedback.png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            label.text = @"About us";
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about.png"];
            
        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    [cell addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 4;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 90;
}
```

The thing is some separator line is missing and some are not, this really confusing me.

[image]

So what may have caused this problem?

### EDIT

To those who may concern, this screenshot is not on a simulator but was captured on an ihpone device.

And the line was originally showed except that after scrolling down and bouncing back, the line was missing.

Comment: In simulator press command+1. It is not issue of tableview.

Comment: Window->Scale->100%  - your window is small zoom and chekck once

Comment: @BhavinRamani thanks for reply, but I am not using a simulator, I am using a device to develop and that screen shot is captured on an iphone device

Comment: see this for sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601013/uitableviewcell-separator-not-showing-up

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for reply, have read that question before post this one, the OP's problem on that question is none line was showing, my problem is some lines a missing, it maybe not the same problem.

Comment: Are  you create tableview in Interface builder or by code

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish by code and the code was posted. check it out

Comment: Separator line is covered by label. try move subviews to `cell.contentView`.

Comment: change UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  to UITableViewCellStyleDefault and make label background color is clear

Comment: remove separator line and add UILabel with 1px height at end of the cell and set background colour black or light gray (or whatever you color want).

Comment: @melvyndev changing to `[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];` will cause all content missing and the row left blank.

Comment: Remove subviews from contentView not cell

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you're using a custom cell class.
If you are overriding the `layoutSubviews()` method in your cell class implementation, make sure that in the method you have the following:

```
super.layoutSubviews()
```

or in Objective-C:

```
[super layoutSubviews];
```

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

you can do another way,

- remove separator line
- add UILabel with 1px height at end of the cell and set background colour black or light gray (or whatever you want).

Answer (score 0):

write this line in cellforrowatindexPath

```
  cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewStylePlain;
```

and drag n drop a UILabel with view controller Width And Height 1px at the bottom of the content view see the blue line in image

do stuff in storyboard

[image]

After reloading table on Device,See image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my case, it was the Clip To Bounds on the custom UITableViewCell. Accidentally deselected it from the storyboard. Then again setting Clip To Bounds to true resolve this issue. Please do this thing it solve your issue.

Objective-C

```
[cell setClipToBound: YES];
```

Swift

```
cell.clipToBound = true
```

Storyboard :-

UITableViewCell OR UITableViewCell XIB

[image]

Thank You.